# Ruby On Rails — installing git-based gems 'not ckecked out' problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

Having a problem with git-based gems.
gem file contents:
...
gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git', :branch => '0-60-stable'
...
then 'bundle install' and it installs the gem
but after I make 'bundle check' I get this error:
'git://github.com/spree/spree.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run bundle install'
I have this error for ANY gem with git source. Gem is 100% working and has been tested on other machines.

any ideas?
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0];
ruby -Rails 3.0.7;
Bundler version 1.1.pre.4;
Mac OS X 10.6.6

Tried to reinstall ruby and rails from a scratch using this document   http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/

Also tried with rvm using ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 and different bundler versions. Always get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the mysql2 gem listed in the Gemfile, it didn't want to install correctly and caused further errors with all other gems. After removing mysql2 from the Gemfile everything worked well.

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass a valid url through the git parameter so

```
gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git', :branch => '0-60-stable'
```

is erroring out because it doesn't recognize git as a valid protocol try:

```
gem 'spree', :git => 'http://github.com/spree/spree.git', :branch => '0-60-stable'
```

Comment: git:// is a valid protocol for Gemfile